# Hi-Tech C Compiler struct of bits

Tags: c, struct

I am using the MPLAB X IDE with Hi-Tech C Compiler on an PIC-controller.
Therefore it is important ti thing a little bit "Byte-orientated".
So I try the following:

```
volatile struct{
   unsigned bit white:1;
   unsigned bit red:1;
   unsigned bit blue:1;
   unsigned bit green:1;
   unsigned bit violett:1;//Magenta
   unsigned bit yellow:1;
}ColorPick;
```

Now I am not sure if it is declared correctly and What happens, when I drop some Bit-Shifting over that.
In My Result it should only be one bit aktive (1) and all other low (0).

So is "white the bit 0b00000001 or 0b10000000 ?
And when I shift it 6 times I will get yellow. And after that white again.
Can I do that in an identically funktion call of ColorPick << 1; ?

I guess the 1 get shifted to bit 7 and 8 I did not declared as such.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Hi-Tech C User Manual, page 346:

> **A.9.4 The order of allocation of bit-fields within an int (6.5.2.1)**
>
> The first bit-field defined in a structure is allocated the least
>   significant bit position in the storage unit. Subsequent bit-fields
>   are allocated higher-order bits.

Based on the documentation, I don't think that `bit` is a keyword in your compiler.

It has been my experience that bitfields are compiler dependent.  The way I determine the bit alignments is to write a little command line program that does something like this:

```
union test_u {
   struct test_s {
      unsigned long bwhite : 1;
      unsigned long bred : 1;
      unsigned long bblue : 1;
      unsigned long bgreen : 1;
      unsigned long bviolet : 1;
      unsigned long byellow : 1;
      unsigned long bpink : 1;
   } bits;
   unsigned long unlong;
} bitest;

bitest.unlong = 0;
bitest.bred = 1;
printf("0x%8.8X\n", bitest.unlong);
```

Then substitute values in as needed to see where your compiler sticks them.  If you need to communicate with other computers/compilers, you would probably be better off using masks and shifts yourself.